# Add the traffic information to google navigation app

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, navigation

Google navigation is a very powerful app. But the problem in my city is that it don't support the traffic information to suggest the best way.

There is a resource to get the traffic information in my city with a picture which updates the information every 15 minutes: http://www.tehrantraffic.com/trafficmap/ShowImage.asp

My idea is about to write an iOS or Android app which parses this picture and prepares the traffic data. After that, add it to the Google navigation default procedure to get a better result.

Is this possible? Does the Google navigation or Google maps API allow me to write an application like this?

Answer (score 0):

yes it is get the image of a certain area identified by coordinates and at a certain zoom level THEN you have png and just need to add it as a groundOverlay :)

it works for INRIX here